# Edit the editor in bash and other shells

Tags: shell, editors, set

Executing the `fc` builtin causes `bash` and other shells to fire up
`$FCEDIT` on the last command.

Because FCEDIT is a variable, this is inherently customizable.

Is it possible to also customize the editor that starts up when I press `v` in the command mode of `set -o vi` mode?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, the latter command follows whatever is set in `$EDITOR`, e.g., doing:

```
EDITOR=editor
FCEDIT=editor
editor(){ vim +'set ft=sh' "$@"; }
```

Will cause `vim`, defaulting to `sh` syntax, to open for both `v` presses in command mode and for `fc`.

**Edit**:
   Thanks to [alexander-batischev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167612/alexander-batischev) for pointing out that

```
EDITOR=editor
editor(){ vim +'set ft=sh' "$@"; }
```

is sufficient.

(
Interestingly,

```
EDITOR="vim +'set ft=sh'"
```

works for `v`, but not for `fc`, hence the `editor` function workaround.

)

Comment: I didn't expect to figure it out by myself so quick, but maybe someone will find this useful (not sure if to keep it here now).

Comment: Actually, `EDITOR` is used by `fc` as a fallback if `FCEDIT` is not set, so you can get away with setting only `EDITOR`.

Comment: It is useful. It shows how to tell `vim` that the file type is `sh` and thus gives a possibility of getting the right syntax highlighting etc. even though `vim` can't see a file name with a `.sh` suffix. That would not been possible without the use of that shell function I think. Maybe you could expand on the answer a bit?

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev But setting `EDITOR` and leaving `FCEDIT` unset may have the side effect that other programs who invoke `EDITOR` may not do the right thing...

Comment: @Kusalananda You're right, but there's no going around setting `EDITOR`. My suggestion only helps make the solution a bit shorter, that's all.